# What does "popping cans off walls" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Bullet says to Patrick:

> Bullet: I saw you had your pistol license already. So, this is the pre-assignment
> training course. We got eight hours together, **popping cans off walls** and the like.

What does "popping cans off walls" mean?

Comment: "Popping" here is used to means "shooting".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really have this experience but I imagine it simply describes the setup of an excercise: There are cans set on top of a wall and the task is to shoot them down.